# XSLT for-each with inner if statement doesn't affect position starting by 1, it starts by 5

Tags: c++, xml, xslt

I have a for-each loop where I have added an inner if statement to filter over my application. The application that is related is not directly referenced within the nodes I am looping over.

It is rather formularfield -> formular -> application and the xml structure is flat, not hierarchically.

If I filter with such a if statement, I will get a position starting at 5 and not 1:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//lbDMF/formularfields/formular[@tablename=$FKTable]">
<xsl:variable name="DisplayField1" select="@fkname"/> 
<xsl:variable name="FKFormularRefId" select="@formularid"/>
<xsl:if test="//lbDMF/formulare/formular[@ID=$FKFormularRefId][@applicationid=$ApplicationID]/@applicationid=$ApplicationID">
Foo.VisibleIndex = <xsl:value-of select="position()-1"/>;
```

My question is as follows: Can I move the inner if condition into the for-each select?

If, how could I do this (I tried and failed)?

If there is a different way to filter, would I affect the position?

I am using libxslt from my C++ application and not any java based xslt processor.

Thanks,

Lothar

Comment: You might want to post a small but representative sample of the XML input and explain us which condition you want to check and which result you want to achieve. Also show us your attempt and explain in which way it failed (e.g. syntax error, semantic error).

Answer (score 0):

In general, with cross-references you can works with keys and set up

```
<xsl:key name="table-name" match="lbDMF/formularfields/formular" use="@tablename"/>
```

that way the expression `//lbDMF/formularfields/formular[@tablename=$FKTable]` can be shortened to `key('table-name', $FKTable)`.

Then you can set up a second key

```
<xsl:key name="id" match="lbDMF/formulare/formular" use="@ID"/>
```

and now you can write `//lbDMF/formulare/formular[@ID=$FKFormularRefId]` as `key('id', $FKFormularRefId)`.

I am not sure why you have `@applicationid=$ApplicationID` both in a predicate expression and in the last step, that seems redundant.

So using the keys I think you can use

```
<xsl:for-each select="key('table-name', $FKTable)[key('id', @formularid)/@applicationid=$ApplicationID]">
  Foo.VisibleIndex = <xsl:value-of select="position()-1"/>;
</xsl:for-each>
```